# What is the standard workflow for using drake with real robot?

Tags: drake

I would like to use `Drake` to control a real robot (Franka panda or Kuka iiwa). For simulation, the standard workflow would be build a diagram first and then use the `Simulator` to simulate the diagram. However, for the usage in real robot, I haven't found an example on how to run the built diagram. A close example would be [`ManipulationStationHardwareInterface`](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/examples/manipulation_station/manipulation_station_hardware_interface.h). However I haven't found code on how to actual use this interface. Do I need to manually generate the `context` and run the diagram in a `while` loop? Or maybe I still need to use the `Simulator` and use the `AdvanceTo` method? If I use the `Simulator`, would there be addtional setting for synchoronization? What's more, how to control the loop frequency of the running diagram?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ManipulationStationHardwareInterface` is indeed a reasonable example to look at.  We have an updated version of the coming to Drake soon, too.

The basic steps are:

- Run the robot's driver as a different process.  Some of the drivers we use are public and are hosted here: https://manipulation.csail.mit.edu/station.html .
- Send / Receive messages from your main controller thread to/from your driver.  The LCMPublisherSystem and LCMSubscriberSystem are right in Drake.  The ROS/ROS2 equivalents are here: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake-ros (The `ManipulationStationHardwareInterface` + `manipulation_station_simulation` file in Drake shows an example of splitting up a Diagram for control + simulation into two processes using this message passing.
- Timing: in the simplest case (typically ok for hardware) all of the executables are running with `simulator.set_target_realtime_rate(1.0)` and then `simulator.AdvanceTo(big number)`.  In other words, they all synchronize their clocks to the cpu clock, and don't try to synchronize explicitly to a clock passed via message passing. That sort of synchronization is possible, too, but I recommend the simpler version first.  In this simple version, each system (e.g. your controller) is set to update with some periodic update -- say 100Hz -- and will run its computation using the most recently received subscribed messages and publish at that rate.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I have one addtional question. In the timing part you say that in the simple version each system is set to update with some periodic update. How to set this periodic update? Is this done in the declaration of `LcmPublisherSystem` and `LcmSubscriberSystem`? For example if I add a `LcmPublisherSystem` to my diagram and connect my controller to it. I set the publish period of this `LcmPublisherSystem` to be 0.005. Does that mean that my controller will be called every 0.005 second?

Comment: For simple diagrams, yes, that is correct.  

In fact, Drake has a substantial description language for discrete + continuous time systems.  Each individual system in your diagram can declare it's own update times (for discrete state), and any continuous derivatives will be called according to the integrator parameters.  But when your LcmPublishSystem publishes (at that rate), it will pull on it's input ports and force all of the necessary evaluations according to the timing semantics of your diagram.

Comment: Will the LcmPublisherSystem be fast enough for dynamic tasks? E.g. Atlas acrobatics. My understanding is there are a lot of intermediate layers in Drake MBP etc., my intuition says this will not be as fast as having some embedded controller in C++ running on the system itself for dynamic task. In that case, we need some way to export all the controllers in a Drake diagram to low-level code for our robot system. Is such a capability available?

Comment: We ran dynamic (e.g. balancing/walking) controllers for Atlas over LCM at 300-400Hz during the DRC, which was sufficient for that robot.  But it's definitely also possible to use Drake c++ controllers running in your driver-level control.  We do this sometimes, too.  The philosophy is that you should be able to think about the Drake diagram that you want, and then split that diagram across different processes by inserting message passing systems at whichever signals are most suitable for your application.